# Динамическая подстановка

Tags: xcode, iphone, objective-c

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите как делать динамические имена?

К примеру есть код

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

[UIView transitionWithView:self.mini5
duration:0.5f
options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
animations:^{
if ([[_lastColor substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,1)] isEqual: @"0"]) {
self.mini5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];}
else if ([[_lastColor substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,1)] isEqual: @"1"]){
self.mini5.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];}
} completion:NULL];

}
```

Как вы видите mini5 это UIImageView, и конечно же есть mini1 и mini2 и т.д.
Как в вышеприведенном коде заменить цифру у всех mini в конце, на значение i цикла?

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте KVC ([NSKeyValueCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)):

```
UIImageView *mini = [self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mini%i", i]];
mini.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
```

Писал в слепую могут быть опечатки. Но думаю суть донес )

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Все работает, теперь буду знать как это делается.

Comment: Да не за что, тоже 3 дня потратил когда с ActionScript переходил.

Comment: А как сделать паузу в 0.5 сек перед каждым выполнением внутри цикла (который выше)?
Пробовал с NSTimer поэксперементировать но что-то не получилось.

Comment: Это тема для другого топика